# How to check out arcgis 10.2 desktop license using arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-license-manager

Referring to [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000000z000000)  it seems possible to check out advanced desktop license. But typing 
`arcpy.CheckOutExtension('ArcInfo')`

gives

`Unrecognized extension code ArcInfo`

Comment: The documentation you cite states that it is required to `import arcinfo` *before* `import arcpy` to checkout that product (which is not an extension).

Comment: you can try...
arcpy.ProductInfo()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation states:

> "SetProduct is a legacy; importing modules needs to be done before importing arcpy".

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SetProduct/03q30000000v000000/

The script might go something like this:

```
import arcinfo  
import arcpy

if arcpy.CheckProduct("ArcInfo") == "Available":  
    execute code  
else:  
    print "Error message"
```

Comment: Mr. Che -- This should be the excepted answer. "Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex."

Comment: @JohnC.King As you wish. =)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue stems from the fact that ArcInfo isn't an extension.

Try using:

```
arcpy.SetProduct('arcInfo')
```

It is customary to use a Try:Except block when setting a product level.

Try using:

```
class LicenseException(Exception):
    pass

try:  
    status = arcpy.SetProduct('arcInfo')
    if status == 'CheckedOut':
        pass
    if status == 'AlreadyInitialized':
        pass
    if status == 'NotLicensed':
        raise LicenseException(status)    # Extends Exception
    if status == 'Failed':
        raise LicenseException(status)

except LicenseException:
    # Handle the exception accordingly.
except:
    # Handle unexpected exceptions.
```

Look here for more information:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/SetProduct/000v0000003w000000/